# Cycle of SecureRandom of Java

Tags: java, random, prng

PRNGs usually have a cycle after which the generated random numbers do repeat. What's the cycle of SecureRandom of Java when the instance of SecureRandom is created as follows:

`SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");`

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused. I had a look into the code of sun.security.provider.SecureRandom of the openjdk. Here the internal state is updated as follows:

```
digest.update(state);
output = digest.digest();
updateState(state, output);
```

[...]

```
private static void updateState(byte[] state, byte[] output) {
    int last = 1;
    int v = 0;
    byte t = 0;
    boolean zf = false;

    // state(n + 1) = (state(n) + output(n) + 1) % 2^160;
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        // Add two bytes
        v = (int)state[i] + (int)output[i] + last;
        // Result is lower 8 bits
        t = (byte)v;
        // Store result. Check for state collision.
        zf = zf | (state[i] != t);
        state[i] = t;
        // High 8 bits are carry. Store for next iteration.
        last = v >> 8;
    }

    // Make sure at least one bit changes!
    if (!zf)
       state[0]++;
}
```

No counter is incremented but the internal state is simply updated with the output.

Comment: A bit of confusion is OK here, as the current implementation in OpenJDK (which seems to be same as in current Oracle JDK) seems to implement the algorithm outlined in my answer. So i guess the official documentation is outdated here, the algorithm implemented has no 64 bit counter and a much bigger internal state (160 bits). Funny this seems to be undocumented, 10+ minutes with Google gave me no better answer...

Answer (score 0):

From the description given in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA:

> SHA1PRNG: The name of the pseudo-random number generation (PRNG)
>   algorithm supplied by the SUN provider. This implementation follows
>   the IEEE P1363 standard, Appendix G.7: "Expansion of source bits", and
>   uses SHA-1 as the foundation of the PRNG. It computes the SHA-1 hash
>   over a true-random seed value concatenated with a 64-bit counter which
>   is incremented by 1 for each operation. From the 160-bit SHA-1 output,
>   only 64 bits are used.

i conclude that the cycle length is only 2^64 (assumed there are no backdoors built in)

Comment: The explanation is a bit fuzzy, but I don't feel like reading through the IEEE P1363 standard right now..

Comment: You can't conflate the bit length with the cycle length. -1

Comment: @EJP: The description mentions a 64 bit counter, which would conclude a 64 bit cycle length (unless there is other state in the PRNG)!

Comment: It doesn't imply any such thing. Your reasoning is fallacious. The description also mentions a lot of other things which you have completely ignored. Don't just cherry-pick the bits you like.

Comment: From the description given, i'd assume the "SHA-1 hash over a true-random seed" stays fixed for the lifetime of the PRNG instance (there is no mentioning of a feedback of the calculated hash). If only the 64 bit counter is incremented for each calculation, its cycle must be 2^64, and thus the cycle of the entire PRNG

Comment: @EJP The Java 1.7 documentation certainly does not explain the algorithm used, and according to the answer of Gyro the algorithm has indeed changed. In other words, don't count on the implementation of SHA1PRNG to remain constant in time.